# Why do i have to link OpenGL lib manually with MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, opengl, gcc, mingw

I have the following gcc command that work correctly:

```
gcc -Wall -g hello_gl.c -lglut32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -o hello_gl && hello_gl
```

I would like to avoid the pain to link manually each OpenGl lib, and thus find a way to make MinGW understand that *glut32, openGL32, glu32* are all located in *C:\MinGW\lib* .

I have try to set the following windows envar following MinGW official doc :

```
CPATH        = C:\MinGW\include
LIBRARY_PATH = C:\MinGW\lib
```

But when i try to simply run this:

```
gcc -Wall -g hello_gl.c -o hello_gl && hello_gl
```

MinGW can't find the OpenGL lib.

I have also try to force the lib path in the gcc command:

```
gcc -Wall -g -IC:\MinGW\include hello_gl.c -LC:\MinGW\lib -o hello_gl && hello_gl
```

But again MinGW was not able to find the OpenGL lib.

So i would like to know if

> - Linking manually all lib included is an obligation with OpenGL Lib ?
> - If yes why is that so ?
> - If not how could i do to solve my problem and force MinGW to find them ?

Cheers

Comment: There so many different kinds of apps that if any compiler would follow your idea, every lib should be automatically added to any project. That be sooooo low performance. Also, if you have a different lib, you know why, it will confused with an "automatic" lib with the same name in other dir.

Comment: Thanks Ripi2, It does make sense.

Comment: I suspect you've asked this because you're typing the build command manually and want to save on typing. Consider using a build system like `make` instead, or at least a build script.

Comment: exactly i type those manually :) basically a build script would be a bash file containing the gcc command ? and the pro version of this would be i guess to start writing makefile ? you are right ! Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below command doesn't tell gcc to build with any libraries, just where to find them.

```
gcc -Wall -g -IC:\MinGW\include hello_gl.c -LC:\MinGW\lib -o hello_gl && hello_gl
```

you have to include the -l[libraryname] options, otherwise, how else would it know which libraries you wanted to link with, in much the same way that you have to tell it which source or object files you want to build with.

Comment: Thanks Chris , so i must include the lib manually with -l to tell gcc that i want to build with them. No Choice !